# Add addition forms/templates dynamically in Django Form Wizard

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-formwizard

Is there a way to add additional forms and templates to the form wizard based on user input in step 0?

for example:

Currently, my forms and templates are set as:

```
FORMS = [("verify", VerifyAccountsForm)]

TEMPLATES = {
    "0": "verify_user_accounts_wizard.html"
        }
```

If user enters a certain input, I would like to add another step to the form wizard, extending FORMS and templates to:

```
FORMS = [("verify", VerifyAccountsForm),
    ("answer_question", AnswerQuestionForm)]

TEMPLATES = {
    "0": "verify_user_accounts_wizard.html",
    "1": "answer_question_wizard.html"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form list needs to be defined beforehand and should not be changed (I'm not sure if it's even possible, it probably involves a lot of hacky/messy code).

Instead you should define both forms and optionally (depending on the first form selection) skip the second step.

Please refer to django wizard docs on how to conditionally skip steps.

Comment: the condition_dict seems to require a field in the form to trigger.  the next step is determined by other information the user enter (not an explicit field). However can I implement condition_dict without this explicit field?